# "Как" в значении "в качестве"

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение такого типа: "Как честный человек(,) я обязан на ней жениться". После "человека" интонационно просится запятая, но тут ведь "как" в значении "в качестве". Так нужна запятая или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая здесь нужна, значение "как" здесь не "в качестве", а "будучи".  В этом случае запятая ставится. Ср.: Будучи честным человеком, я обязан на ней жениться. - Так как я честный человек, я обязан на ней жениться. Выражение "как честный человек" имеет обстоятельственное значение.